# Get random IDs for ranking

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Nuxt.js and I get some random pictures by URL like this :

```
http://www.randomimage.com?ID=myId
```

I get 2 pictures by doing this :

```
getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return this.numb = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
},
addImage() {
  let img = document.getElementById('img')
  img.src = 'http://portailservices/portail/fichier.php?LI=' +  this.getRandomArbitrary(20, 700);
},
```

Now I want visitors to upvote between 2 pictures and store it in the localstorage to have a rank.

But I don't know how can I store Ids I got randomly.

Comment: so store the generated id as a data attribute and reference it..

Comment: Can store the id as dataset property of the image element

Comment: store in in a variable `var myRandomId = this.getRandomArbitrary(20, 700);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the better way to do that is to make parent function where you can generate all two random numbers. Then you can simply save them in localstorage. After this you should invoke your functions with a parameter. Something like this

```
function genAndSaveAndShow() {
  let rnd1 = genRandom(1,10),
      rnd2 = genRandom(1,10);
  saveInfoToStorage({userId: 1, numbers: [rnd1, rnd2]});
  addImage(rnd1);
  addImage(rnd2);
}
```